# Manual install Robot Framework on standalone machine

Tags: python, selenium, testing, robotframework

I'm installing RF on a standalone server (Win 2012 R2 64bit) for the first time that is permanently isolated from any Internet connection.

Whats the best way to install selenium2libray without Internet connection e.g. see step 1.4

> Note You should have an internet connection to perform this
>   installation

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html

So far:

1. --version says .. installed RF 3.0.2 with Python 2.7.14 on Win32
2. this lives in c:\Python27
3. folder call RFTests has the test suite.

The error I get when running a test is:

```
  [ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\RoboFrameworkTests\Tests\2179.robot': Importing test library 'selenium2library' failed: ImportError: No module named selenium2library
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  None
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\python27.zip
  C:\Python27\DLLs
  C:\Python27\lib
  C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
  C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
  C:\Python27
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\robotframework_selenium2library-3.0.0-py2.7.egg
  C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
```

Obviously I can't download any dependencies, so have to do this manually.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong case for library reference: I was using selenium2library when it should have been Selenium2Library